# postgres trigger pass input to function

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to make a trigger that when a value is put into table1 it is then copied into table2. I have the following function which works correctly:

```
Create function func1(a integer) returns void
Language SQL as $$
insert into table2 values (a);$$;
```

and here is the trigger (it doesn't work):

```
Create trigger trig1
Before update on table1
For each row
Execute function func1(old.attr1)
```

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html) documentation. Here is the part in particular I am following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON accounts
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_account_update();
```

I figured that old.attribute gives a particular attribute of the old row before it is changed. If I'm wrong on this let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) says this about the function that is called in the trigger:

> A user-supplied function that is declared as taking no arguments and
>   returning type trigger, which is executed when the trigger fires.

This function has access to the `OLD` and `NEW` objects. You can modify your existing function:

```sql
Create function func1()  RETURNS trigger
as $$
 BEGIN
   insert into table2 values (OLD.attr1);   
   RETURN NEW; 
 END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Create trigger trig1
  Before update on table1
  For each row
  Execute function func1();
```

Comment: when I try to make the fuction func1 as you describe i get this error: "SQL functions cannot return type trigger"